# Custom shape of PopupMenuButton in flutter

Tags: flutter, customization, shapes, triangle, popupmenubutton

I wan to change the shape of my PopupMenuButton in flutter, want to add a triangle on top as shown in below picture, I have spent a lot of time on google but no achievement please help me out I am new to flutter so I do not know how to change this default container, now it simply has white rounded container, white arrow/triangle is not being added on top of it. please help out, thanks in advance

```
 popUpMenu= PopupMenuButton<String>(
     key: _menuKey,
     offset: Offset(50,100),
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
     onSelected: (value) {
       if (value == "Tax & Additional Charges") {
         endDrawerController.drawerKey.value =
             EndDrawerKeys.TaxAndAdditionalChargesEndDrawer;
         endDrawerController.scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
         print("Entering in tax");
       } else if (value == "Hold this Invoice") {
         endDrawerController.drawerKey.value =
             EndDrawerKeys.HoldInvoiceEndDrawer;
         endDrawerController.scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
       }
     },
     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.h))),
     itemBuilder: (context) => [
       PopupMenuItem(
         value: "Tax & Additional Charges",
         child: popUpMenuSingleItem(
             icon: AppAssets.DeliveryIcon,
             text: "Tax & Additional Charges",
             topMargin: 15.h),
       ),
       PopupMenuItem(
         value: "Hold this Invoice",
         child: popUpMenuSingleItem(
             icon: AppAssets.DeliveryIcon,
             text: "Hold this Invoice",
             topMargin: 25.h),
       ),
     ],
    );
```

This is how I want my PopupMenuButton to be appear

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html#widgets.CustomPaint.1)?

Comment: Yes I have, I have created triangle through CustomPaint but do not know how to wrap in around PopupMenuButton container , I wrapped it once around  PopupMenuButton  but triangle is being added on PopupMenu option button which is right in appbar which I do not want , I want to add triangle around PopupMenuButton container as shown in above picture

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a shape for your custom `PopupMenuButton`.

Sample...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton(
            offset: Offset(0, 50),
            shape: const TooltipShape(),
            itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuEntry>[
              PopupMenuItem(
                  child: ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.calculate_outlined),
                title: const Text('Tax & Additional Charges'),
              )),
              PopupMenuItem(
                  child: ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(Icons.av_timer_outlined),
                title: const Text('Hold This Invoice'),
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// I'm using [RoundedRectangleBorder] as my reference...
class TooltipShape extends ShapeBorder {
  const TooltipShape();

  final BorderSide _side = BorderSide.none;
  final BorderRadiusGeometry _borderRadius = BorderRadius.zero;

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.all(_side.width);

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(
    Rect rect, {
    TextDirection? textDirection,
  }) {
    final Path path = Path();

    path.addRRect(
      _borderRadius.resolve(textDirection).toRRect(rect).deflate(_side.width),
    );

    return path;
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    final Path path = Path();
    final RRect rrect = _borderRadius.resolve(textDirection).toRRect(rect);

    path.moveTo(0, 10);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, 0, 10, 0);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width - 30, 0);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width - 20, -10);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width - 10, 0);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(rrect.width, 0, rrect.width, 10);
    path.lineTo(rrect.width, rrect.height - 10);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(
        rrect.width, rrect.height, rrect.width - 10, rrect.height);
    path.lineTo(10, rrect.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(0, rrect.height, 0, rrect.height - 10);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: _side.scale(t),
        borderRadius: _borderRadius * t,
      );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed it was so kind of you

Comment: @rrickimaru thank you so much!. I have a doubt what we need to do when we want the clip in the left side instead or fright ?

Comment: @SangeethaSakthivel Just play on the values of `path` in `TooltipShape::getOuterPath(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class PopMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PopMenuState createState() => _PopMenuState();
}

class _PopMenuState extends State<PopMenu> {
  List<Icon> icons = [
    Icon(Icons.person),
    Icon(Icons.settings),
    Icon(Icons.credit_card),
  ];
  GlobalKey _key = LabeledGlobalKey("button_icon");
  OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  Offset _buttonPosition;
  bool _isMenuOpen = false;

  void _findButton() {
    RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    _buttonPosition = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
  }

  void _openMenu() {
    _findButton();
    _overlayEntry = _overlayEntryBuilder();
    Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry);
    _isMenuOpen = !_isMenuOpen;
  }

  void _closeMenu() {
    _overlayEntry.remove();
    _isMenuOpen = !_isMenuOpen;
  }

  OverlayEntry _overlayEntryBuilder() {
    return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) {
        return Positioned(
          top: _buttonPosition.dy + 50,
          left: _buttonPosition.dx - 250,
          width: 300,
          child: _popMenu(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _popMenu() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
            child: ClipPath(
              clipper: ArrowClipper(),
              child: Container(
                width: 17,
                height: 17,
                color: Color(0xFFF67C0B9),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFF67C0B9),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          ),
          child: Theme(
            data: ThemeData(
              iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: List.generate(
                icons.length,
                (index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      width: 300,
                      height: 100,
                      child: icons[index],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          key: _key,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFF5C6373),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
          ),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              _isMenuOpen ? _closeMenu() : _openMenu();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ArrowClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```